# Mixing storyboard and constraints in code

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, autolayout

I'm trying to implement view controller from this wireframe

[image]

As we have different screen resolutions - different number of yellow views can fit on the screen. All yellow views are same size `UIImageView`s, containing the same image.

What I'm trying to do is to layout view controller in storyboard except the yellow views. Then I calculate number of yellow views screen can fit and add them using auto layout in code. Like this:

```
let numberOfViewsPerSide = numberOfViewsOnEachSide()
let viewImage = UIImage (named: "repeat_image")
var prevView = centerImageView
if let viewImage = viewImage {
    for index in 0...(numberOfViewsPerSide - 1) {
        var newView = UIImageView(image: viewImage)
        newView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        let views = ["prevView" : prevView, "newView" : newView]

        self.view.addSubview(newView)
        let constraint_H = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[newView]-15-[prevView]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllCenterY, metrics: nil, views: views)
        self.view.addConstraints(constraint_H)
        prevView = newView
    }
}
```

The problem is that in `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear` methods auto layout isn't triggered yet. So `centerImageView` doesn't have right size and position. Moreover its superview is `nil` at this point. So I basically can't add constraint to view without parent.
My code works in `viewDidAppear` method but that means that all yellow views will appear only after transition animation is completed.

Do you have any idea how to implement that without doing everything in storyboard or purely in code. `UILabel`, `UIButton` on the picture positioned deleted to the green `centerView` - if I add `centerView` in code I need to set all constraints for this screen in code.

**UPDATE:**
Solution offered by @pteofil worked for me
so I call code above in `viewWillAppear` like that:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        addRepeatedImages()
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried it in `viewWillLayoutSubviews()` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`?

Comment: You need call `layoutIfNeeded` on self.view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `layoutIfNeeded` to get the autolayout triggered and have your views the correct size.

But your yellow views almost looks like you could use a `UICollectionView` to manage them...

Comment: `UICollectionView` will be an overkill here. I don't need to scroll it. That is a line of the static images.

Answer (score 1):

You can embed all the yellow views in a container view you position in interface builder. Now you can do all the stuff inside this view in code.